# Reuse of Regex group in row

Tags: php, regex

I try to reuse a regex group.

What I have:

```
Other Stuff 
Other Stuff
Anker: 'Result1' 'Result2' 'Result3' 'Result4' 'ResultN'
Other Stuff
Other Stuff
```

What I want:

```
$aVariable = [Result1, Result2, Result3, Result4, ResultN];
```

What I have tried:

```
Anker:(?: '(.*?)')+
```

(And trust me, many, many other regexes, but I don't get it.)

What is the correct way to get multiple elements in on single row?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which lang you're running?

Comment: At the moment I am running this in regex buddy, which is language independent. I am interessed in the Regex, not in the implementation in a specific language

Comment: If you are using C#, it is very easy with `Captures` collection. Please add your language tag to the question. Here you are, try in RegexBuddy: [`(?m)^Anker:(?:\s*('[^']*'))+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fm)%5eAnker%3a(%3f%3a%5cs*(%27%5b%5e%27%5d*%27))%2b&i=Other+Stuff+%0d%0aOther+Stuff%0d%0aAnker%3a+%27Result1%27+%27Result2%27+%27Result3%27+%27Result4%27+%27ResultN%27%0d%0aOther+Stuff%0d%0aOther+Stuff), (see **Tables** tab at *RegexStorm.net*).

Comment: Regex is language / tool dependent. Some features are not supported in some, some syntax varies across different languages, some languages provide functionality such as finding the first match only or matching the entire string rather than just part of it.

Comment: What you want is actually not clear. A simple find all `"/(?<=[ ]').*?(?=')/"` gets it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below `\G` anchor based regex.

```
$re = "/(?:^Anker:|\\G(?!^))\\h*'([^']*)'/m";
$str = "Other Stuff \nOther Stuff\nAnker: 'Result1' 'Result2' 'Result3' 'Result4' 'ResultN'\nOther Stuff\nOther Stuff";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xY8pK9/1)

Comment: You sir, deserve a badge!

Comment: This example won't require any assertions. `(?:^Anker:|\G)\h*'([^']*)'` :-)